# Can Cloudstack be used to manage Rackspace Cloud servers

Tags: virtualization, cloud, rackspace

Specifically, I'm looking at the latest version of Cloudstack, the 2.2.9.1RC..  I can't find in the documentation anything specifically saying whether cloudstack supports or does not support Rackspace Cloud at this time.

Is there a comprehensive list somewhere of all the available VM / Cloud environment managers that Cloudstack supports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rackspace cloud is built upon the openstack.

cloudstack is a tool to enable you to manage virtual servers but it requires you to have physical servers to do the virtual server hosting.

rackspace cloud in its raw form available to the end user is NOT compatible with cloudstack, besides virtualising servers in a virtual environment is 99% not worth it and I believe you can only virtualise openvz within a xen environment (with some work and not recommended)

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't thinking to virtualize the rackspace cloud servers themselves, but to manage the rackspace cloud servers alongside any other VMs I were to create.

Comment: yeah cloudstack doesnt work like that with 3rd party providers... you need your own hardware

Answer (score 3):

CloudStack is NOT based on OpenStack.

CloudStack started in 2008, written in Java.

OpenStack started in 2010 and is written in Python.

And no, you can't manage RackSpace Cloud. CloudStack is for running your own cloud, be it a public cloud offering cloud services like Godaddy, KT, or Tata; or a private cloud internal to your company like Zynga, Edmunds.com, etc.